# Initializing collections that contain nested collections

Tags: c#

How do I initialize a collection of 'Quote' objects based on the class shown below where 'Quote' would contain a collection of at least 5 'Rate' objects.

```
    List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote> {new Quote { Id = 1, (need 5 Rate objects in here) } }

public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccommodationType { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote> {
  new Quote { 
    Id = 1, 
    Rates = new List<Rate> {
      new Rate { Id = 1, ...},
      new Rate { Id = 2, ...},
      ...
    } 
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: +1, you can also use shorthand `(new []{new Rate{Id = ...}, ...}).ToList()` if that is more clear

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this. Who or what is the down voter ?

Comment: You can vote down on answers. Its a legitimate way to state your opinion towards an asnwer but iit'd be nice when a downvoter gives a reason. Even so, the downvoter here changed his opinion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create such object graphs for you.

Comment: +1, This is a good recommendation, but it probably isn't the type of answer the OP was looking for.  My guess is the downvote is because this is a 'best practices' answer and the questions reads more like it's looking for syntax.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for syntax. Although I am interested in other way of creating the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote> {
  new Quote { 
    Id = 1,
    Rates = new List<Rate> {
      new Rate {
        Id = 1,
        AccommodationType = "Whatever",
        Price = 0m
      },
      new Rate { ......
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Really? The property name seems to be missing. I dare say, my version is more correct :)

Comment: Fixed. Your version is missing the final semicolon. Chew on that :)

Comment: Excellent. Just had to repair :)